# Does it make sense to have an Assistant Manager with no Manager?

Tags: new-job, job-description, title

I have recently interviewed at a company for an Assistant Manager position. It is my understanding that I would be managing a group of employees in a single department at Facility A to do a number of different tasks.

The odd part is, I would not be reporting to a "Manager" but to a "Director" who oversees multiple departments at multiple facilities. Does this make sense? To make it more odd, at Facility B the same department (also reporting to this Director) has a Manager but no Assistant Manager. I understand it's just semantics and that "Director" could probably be interchangeable with "Manager", but it seems like they should be offering a "Manager" title rather than "Assistant Manager". I'm not looking for more pay, it just seems silly to have an Assistant Manager without a manager; not sure how this works in other companies?

As an aside, I was told the reason for the specific title is that the organization is moving away from "Manager" titles, and yet after this interview a Manager job was posted in another department at the same company.

Comment: Is title really important?

Comment: "As an aside, I was told the reason for the specific title is that the organization is moving away from "Manager" titles, and yet after this interview a Manager job was posted in another department at the same company." So what? They said they were moving away. They never said they had moved away.

Comment: "The odd part is, I would not be reporting to a "Manager" but to a "Director" who oversees multiple departments at multiple facilities. Does this make sense?" Is there a reason why it does not make sense, or are you absolutely hung up on the title of "Manager" as the position you are to report to?

Comment: "I'm not looking for more pay, it just seems silly to have an Assistant Manager without a manager; not sure how this works in other companies?" Does it matter? More importantly, how does it negatively impact any work that you do for them? In fact, how does it impact you at all?

Comment: @Vietnhi I imagine customers stating, "Oh you're the assistant manager? I want to speak to the manager." "There is no manager. But you can speak to the Director of x, y, and z." Not to mention interoperability with other departments; they may not be interested in working with me on projects and enhancements because I am not the manager of the department.

Comment: Make your concern known to the Director and other management after you are hired. In the meantime: 1. I'd say instead "I'll get you to AAA, who is the Director and my boss"; 2. They may not be interested with you because your title says "Assistant Manager" but your Director should be able to straighten out any miscommunication. If you are Assistant Manager and there is no Manager, then you are Acting Manager. Up to a point.

Comment: Let me be blunt. They want you to manage but they don't see you as equal to other managers in the company. It's really no more complicated than that.

Answer (score 3):

It's just semantics.

For some reason, they don't want you as a full Manager quite yet.

Perhaps you need more experience, or need to demonstrate your leadership ability, or just need to be there for a while. Then you may be in line for a promotion to Manager.

I've worked at companies that had Supervisors report to Vice Presidents. I've been a Manager that reported to a CTO. I've seen Vice Presidents report to other Vice Presidents. I've been a Director yet still carried a full Individual Contributor workload myself. These titles usually aren't all that important, and don't necessarily convey the work you do very accurately.

Feel fortunate that you most likely have a clear path to your next promotion, without having to wait for someone else to leave or get promoted.

Comment: I suspect it is the goal of most startups to be bought out by a larger company.  They will be thinking how to seamlessly transition to being part of a larger organization - which is why you'll have Vice Presidents without Presidents, etc.

Answer (score 0):

By your line

> As an aside, I was told the reason for the specific title is that the organization is moving away from "Manager" titles, and yet after this interview a Manager job was posted in another department at the same company

It seem that your company might looking forward to have a manager too.But you might not be aware of that or they might be hiring later or sooner.
Moreover director would have to look forward to other departments too,So he won't be as responsive as much a manager would have been.And in my sense you would be getting a manager to report to soon.
And as said by other's designations doesn't matter a much.

And you'll need to work to fill up the gap, by lack of manager so that productivity is not attracted

Comment: I do not believe that is the case, as I have been explicitly told no manager will be hired in the department and that I will be reporting to the Director.

Comment: You should have referred that in your question